# Sixth Generation Toyota Camry - HVAC Defrost Mode Actuator Installation Instructions Needed

Tags: toyota, camry, hvac

I am working on my car, which is a sixth generation Toyota Camry. She's been great to me..so far. Mine in particular is a 2008.

The issue pertains to the HVAC system. While hot (and cold) air does flow through the lateral driver/passenger window vents and the front windshield defrost vents, air does not flow through the two center vents above the stereo.

After watching several YouTube videos that cover various vehicle types (including an older generation of Toyota Camry), I decided I would try and dive in to learn more about the problem. I've learned more about my car than I ever thought I would.

I removed the glove compartment and the plastic trim behind the glove compartment. I could see the blend and defrost mode actuator assembly, but I removed the passenger foot vent to get more visibility on the actuator assembly.

Even though I changed from defrost mode to other modes with the mode dial on the A/C Climate Control Unit, the actuator and gears did not turn to open up the center vent to allow air through the center dash vents above the stereo. Thus, it looks like the Camry A/C system is stuck in defrost mode. I can feel cold air coming out of the window vents a little.

So here's where I need advice..

I have looked all over the web for instructions on how to complete the repair. Removing the old HVAC Defrost Mode Actuator, and installing the new one.

To be honest, I've a lot of time looking for installation instructions on lining up the gears and whatnot for the install. I've looked all over the internet for instructions, illustrations, or videos that would help, but I can't seem to find the guidance I need. I have found several videos pertaining to removing the blend door actuator in various Camry models, but no videos on installing the HVAC defrost mode actuator.

I'm not sure if the Climate Control Unit needs to be set to a certain mode for the repair, how to line things up, ect.

Any detailed repair/installation advice and instructions would be greatly appreciated!

Link to the Part:

https://www.oemgenuineparts.com/oem-parts/toyota-hvac-defrost-mode-door-actuator-8710633290

Comment: [One of these videos might help you.](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=2008+toyota+camry+blend+door+actuator+replacement+) ... you're looking for the "blend door actuator".